# Add 'commas' separator between all array elements and 'and' before the last array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display array item of an array in a single line divided by 'commas' but the last array item should be preceded by 'and' and a full stop should be added at the end of the last element.

For example:

```
var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "ZEST", "Audi");
```

Should be displayed as **Saab, Volvo, BMW, ZEST and Audi.**

```
var cars = new Array("Saab", "Audi");
```

If there are only 2 items then it should display as **Saab and Audi.**

```
var cars = new Array("Saab");
```

If there is only 1 item it should display as **Saab.**

The array length is dynamic but it should follow the above format i.e. all array item should be separated by commas but there should be 'and' between 2nd last array item and last array item.

```
var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "ZEST", "Audi");

for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

  var total = cars.length;
  var lastbut = total - 1;
  var disp;
  var addand = "";


  if (i != cars.length - 1) {
    disp = ", "
  } else {
    addand = "and "
    disp = "."
  }


  document.write(addand + cars[i] + disp);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f01ph8pa/2/

I am not able to complete this. Can you please help?

Comment: This question is **not about Java**. It is **JavaScript**, two completely different programming languages that have nothing in common (except the name). Please always make sure to use the correct tags to get the right experts to your question.

Comment: Hi @Zabuza yes it's Javascript. I added Javascript and array in the tags.

Answer (score 6):

Use `slice` to get all but the last string in the array and `join` them with a comma; then add " and " and the final string in the array.

```js
function listStrings(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1) {
    return arr[0] + ".";
  }
  return arr.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " and " + arr.at(-1) + ".";
}

console.log(listStrings(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']));
console.log(listStrings(['A', 'B']));
console.log(listStrings(['A']));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stuart. Can we add a full stop after the last item?

Comment: why I can't see any output in JS Fiddle? can we use document.write() to display the results? Please help.

Comment: It's in the browser console. Press Ctrl+Shift+I to view the console in Chrome in windows. Or change the code yourself so it does `document.write` instead of `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

How about the following way? You join the array elements first with a comma and then replace the last comma with ' and '.

```js
        var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "ZEST", "Audi");
        var output = cars.join(",");
        output = output.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,' and '+'$1');
        console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi @VHS thanks a lot but how can I used this in Javascript?

Comment: @Krishnam, the code snippet above is indeed JavaScript.  Just take these 4 lines of code and paste in under your `<script` tag.