# Conditional jQuery string

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I created a couple inputs and one drop down that feed into a JavaScript command to create custom sentences. Whatever the user inputs or selects is added to a sentence framework. When the user selects submit, the sentence is created. It is quite simple. I am running into trouble adding multiple inputs from one drop down to the sentence.

If the user selects "navigation" in addition to "usb ports" within the drop down, it is formatted in the sentence as: "It has these options:  navigation, aux." Similarly if three options are selected it is formatted as: " It has these options:  navigation, aux, usb ports."

How can I edit the code so that if two options are selected an "and" will separate them. "It has these options: navigation and aux." Also, if three of more options are selected an "and" will come before the last value. "It has these options:  navigation, aux, and usb ports."

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hi</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    table,
    td,
    th {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto
    }
    
    .display {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    textarea {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 4
      });
    })
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sentence() {
      document.getElementById("s1").value = ""; // reset
      document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";

      if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
        alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
        document.getElementById("z1").focus();
      } else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
        alert("Mileage is needed");
      } else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
        alert("Exterior color is needed");
      } else {
        const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
        const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
        const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
        var input4 = $('#z4').val();

        document.getElementById("s1").value =
          "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in " +
          input3 + ". It has these options: " + input4 + "."
      }
    }

    function reset() {
      document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
    }

    function hide() {
      document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="hide()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Options" name="options" id="z4" multiple class="chosen-select">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value=" navigation">Navigation</option>
          <option value=" aux">Aux</option>
          <option value=" usb ports">USB Ports</option>
          <option value=" heated seats">Heated Seats</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <div class="display">
    <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="display">
    <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 'commas' separator between all array elements and 'and' before the last array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246597/add-commas-separator-between-all-array-elements-and-and-before-the-last-arra)

Comment: Nope this a question about jquery.

Comment: Which is definitely not Java as your title states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input4` is an array provided by Chosen.

You just have to loop over the values in that array and do what you like... Like adding comas and a "and" before the last value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
 </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    });
  })
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";

    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();
    }

  else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
      alert("Mileage is needed");
    }

else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
      alert("Exterior color is needed");
    }

    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
      const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
      const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
      var input4 = $('#z4').val();
      
      // =======================================
      console.log(input4);  // It is an array.
      
      var input4Formatted = "";
      if(input4.length==1){
        // Only one value...
        input4Formatted = input4[0];
      }
      if(input4.length==2){
        // Two values... Just add and "and"
        input4Formatted = input4[0]+" and"+input4[1];
      }
      if(input4.length>2){
        // more than 2 values...
        for(i=0;i<input4.length-1;i++){
          input4Formatted += input4[i]+",";
        }
        input4Formatted += " and"+input4[input4.length-1];
      }
      // =======================================
      
      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
        + input3 + ". It has these options: " +input4Formatted+ "."

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }


  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
  }


 </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="hide()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select data-placeholder="Options" name="options" id="z4"  multiple class="chosen-select">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=" navigation">Navigation</option>
            <option value=" aux">Aux</option>
            <option value=" usb ports">USB Ports</option>
            <option value=" heated seats">Heated Seats</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```